# meaning of "to schedule out"

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I'm trying to translate the text. My question is: 
what is the meaning of "out of your life" In this sentence

> *Life is made interesting by the unexpected; so don't schedule it **out of your life**. Leaving open times helps you avoid feeling trapped by your schedule and gives you the freedom to enjoy unexpected opportunities as they arise.*

What does it mean? Does that mean in the other context different?

Comment: It means "don't over-organise yourself" -- leave some free time in your daily/weekly schedule to explore unexpected opportunities.

Answer (score 3):

The writer is creating a phrasal verb:

**to schedule** something|someone **out** ....

meaning

"to eliminate the possibility of something (unscheduled) happening by chance, by scheduling an activity for every available time slot"

Here, the "something" is "the unexpected".

The author is saying "Leave some time unscheduled so that the unexpected may enter your life".

Compare "to rule out".

When we *rule* something *out*, we exclude it as a possibility.